# How to add Json file in visual studio in Windows Form app(.Net Framework)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on an Image Gallery Project in Visual Studios 2019 Windows Form app(.Net Framework).
I have a json file from which I will be getting inputs in my class. But as I am new to all this I am not able to figure out how to add this json file into my project.
Can anyone help me how to add Json file into project.
Thanks.

Comment: Its not working brother..

Comment: Is any update? If your question has been solved , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a existing json file, you can refer to ADyson's Solution.

If you want to add a json file directly, you can right click ->add items->choose Json file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the project (or any subfolder) in the visual studio solution explorer, then go to Add -> Existing Item